# C# contravariance with Expression

Tags: c#-4.0

```
public interface IMasterService<out T> : IDisposable
{
        T GetByID(int id);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func);
        int AddNew(T newEntity);
}
```

Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IMasterService.Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. 'T' is covariant.

Comment: remove the out in `<out T>` will avoid error, but I think (hope) you didn't put it just for fun ?

Comment: I surely need <out T> to implement my covariance  with Generics. It works well with GetByID and GetAll Methods. however, where I try work with Where(Expression<FuncT,bool>> it gives me that error.

Answer (score 0):

In short: if you want to use `<out T>` then you should return `T` and if you want to use `<in T>` you need to pass `T` as a parameter. It's not possible to use both `out` and `in` on one interface. Right now I can't say why exactly you can't use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but I'll try to find out something on it.

Comment: Please find below the complete Code and see what I am trying to achieve. Basically Covarince with Generics. It works well for 1st two methods (GetByID & GetAll). But it fails with Where. It gives an error Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IMasterService.Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'. 'T' is covariant.

Find code here http://www.scribd.com/doc/101216821/Code

Comment: `Right now I can't say why exactly you can't use Expression<Func<T, bool>> but I'll try to find out something on it.`, plz checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452614/variance-in-expressionfunct-bool

Comment: `It's not possible to use both out and in on one interface.`, actually you can, e.g. `interface Func<in T, out TResult>`